# Highlight React Material UI TextField "Cell" inside of a React Material UI Table?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, textfield

I'm using React Material UI with TypeScript and I have a Material UI Table with a column of Material TextFields in each row of that column. Now when the user inputs text into the TextField...I want to "highlight" the entire table cell that the TextField is in, not just autofocus on the textfield. How would I accomplish that? Looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the relevant bit of HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, where you just manipulate the DOM directly by toggling classes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/select-table-cell-on-focus-cvime

```
export default function App() {
  const handleFocus = (e: React.FocusEvent) => {
    document
      .querySelectorAll("td")
      .forEach((item) => item.classList.remove("focused"));
    e?.currentTarget?.closest("td").classList.add("focused");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <TextField variant="outlined" onFocus={handleFocus} />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <TextField variant="outlined" onFocus={handleFocus} />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <TextField variant="outlined" onFocus={handleFocus} />
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this pretty much what I need. The only thing is, I need to maintain the the "highlight" after a TextField has changed. So if the original TextField value is 10 and I change it to 15, I need the cell to remain "highlighted" even after I click off the cell. The only time a "changed" cell should be un-highlighted would be if the user reverted the TextField value back to the original value. So instead of `onFocus`, should I use `onChange`?

Comment: I think I need something to manage the state as well...

Comment: Ah ok. In that case I would recommend looking into [Formik-material-ui](https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui) or [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/). Those will manage a `dirty` state that keeps track of whether or not the user has changed the value of an input.

Comment: I was able to use react-hook-form's formstate.dirtyfields to keep track of the state of the changed fields. I modified your handFocus function with the following to get my desired functionality:
`const handleFocus = (e: React.ChangeEvent) => {
        if(!dirtyFields[e?.currentTarget?.id]) {
            document
                .querySelectorAll("td")
                .forEach((item) => item.classList.remove("focused"));
        }
        e?.currentTarget?.closest("td").classList.add("focused");
    };`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **:focus-within** in CSS.

```
div:focus-within {
  background: cyan;
}
```

What it does is when you focus inside something that is focusable like **text-fields**.